# I cannot save mssql table back to not allow null value

Tags: sql-server, null, default-value

Could someone please assist . I've changed  column details properties no allow Null Values and would like to set it back . There are currently null values in this table but I don't want to alter it as it is a Sage accpac table and might cause some data inconsistencies . Because of the null values in it i cannot revert back to it's original state. Please help.

Comment: Can you replace those null values with some sensible default value?

Comment: I don't want to alter the actual data in the Table as it would cause issue with the data consistency of the accounting system. I basically want to change back to not allow null with null values in , as it originally was .

Comment: Absolutely cannot do it - you'll have to come up with a default. The nulls are probably causing downstream problems. You're stuck in a bad spot.